# Check generated ListView time

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-adapter

I would like to know how can i track the time spent to draw/populate a **List View**. I am using a custom array adapter using a List. I was thinking of using `System.nanoTime()`.

I tried with following code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    long startNano = System.nanoTime();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trip_listview, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    TripsArrayAdapter tripsArrayAdapter = new TripsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), CachedData.getInstance().getTripsList());
    lv.setAdapter(tripsArrayAdapter);
    long endNano= System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time create: "+(endNano-startNano));
    return view;
}
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on above code as drawing is not done within `setAdapter` method. What I would do is use [`HierarchyViewer`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) and check how much would each view took to draw and layout.

There is a great article on developer website on [debugging UI](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) and there is [another article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/) from Romain Guy that treats UI performance.

Comment: Thank you, i will check those links. I have improved my layout using HierarchyViewer. But for drawing a huge list (1000+) i dont think it applies the O(n) liniar growth? Or does it?

Comment: Don't forget the listview recycles its views ... If you implemented correctly the recycling you shouldn't concern about large data items.